# How to create a n-level quicknav in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, quick-launch

I am trying to create a quicknav that displays multiple subsites. I thought that this should be a relatively easy thing to do by adjusting a couple of variables - but of course this is SharePoint and nothing is ever easy.

In order to accomplish this, I followed the instructions [found on this site](http://aanuwizard.com/2012/03/sharepoint-2010-customizing-quick-launch-to-pick-up-3-or-more-level-of-sub-menu-items-part-1/). However what I see is in the Quicknav is the following:

[image]

Basically all I did was set StaticDisplayLevels = 5 and MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels = 5 in the masterpage.

Playing around with these variables, I noticed that if StaticDisplayLevels is set to anything more than 2, then the first level of subsites is doubled in the listing. Looking at the links for these items, I see the first item has ".../Pages/default.aspx" and the repeated item has ".../Pages."

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix this?

Comment: have you tried to see what it looks like with tree view enabled?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have to keep StaticDisplayLevels set to 1.

You can increase the fly-outs by changing MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels to 3 or more even.

Reference: http://www.sharepointassist.com/2009/01/14/quick-launch-fly-out-menus/

Comment: I should have mentioned that the requirement is not to have fly-outs, that is why MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels is set to the same number as StaticDisplayLevels. For a lark, I did try this too, and had the same issues. I am beginning to suspect that there is something seriously wrong with my installation - perhaps caused by a 3rd party Feature.

Comment: Have you checked your ULS logs to see if you're getting anything strange?